# Functional equation analysis of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, functional-equations

I got this question in a test of mine and it completely took me by surprise. I just can't "begin" to solve it.

> Let a continuous function $f(x) : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined such that it satisfies the relation
>   $$f(x) + f(x + 2y) + 3xy = 2f(2y – x) + 2y^2 $$
>   for all $x, y\in R$. Comment whether the function is *odd , into , one-one , and invertible.*

I know what these terms necessarily mean in general , but I'm not sure how to check for them here.

I'm always having this general trend of getting troubled by functional equations and the ways of either deriving them or solving them. Apart from this question , it would be great help if anyone could suggest me some text or video where I could learn this topic better. ( The functional equations)

Comment: This isn't a standard question about functional equations... I believe you should solve it by "guessing" values for $x,y$ (e.g for $y=0$ you get that $2f(x)=2f(-x)$).

Comment: What exactly should I aim to find here ? I'm sorry this is all too confusing for me.

Comment: @yanko You mean $2 f(x) = 2 f(-x)$.  $f(x) = 2 f(-x)$ would make things very easy!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for the correction. (edited previous comment)

Comment: @Tanuj, you know the equation is true for any $x,y$ in particular, choosing a value for $y$ will give you an equation involving only $x$. The point is to guess the right values of $y$ that will help solving the question. For example if you substitute $y=0$ you get that the function is even.

Comment: @yanko You mean even.  $x=0$ is even more useful.

Comment: @yanko  That shows that the function is even. Okay, so like this is the only way to check ? By putting random values ?

Comment: If you put the value Robert suggested you will have a good idea what the function is. Try to put $x=0$.

Comment: Guys , it gives me $f(0)=f(2y) + 2y^2$ . What conclusion can I draw from this ?

Comment: @Tanuj can you prove that it is onto now? Is it one to one?

Comment: Not really "random" values, rather ones that are likely to produce simpler equations (involving fewer different values of $f$).  $x=0$ and $y=0$ are often good choices.

Comment: Onto means the range of the function should be equal to the codomain , i.e. $R$ . How do I figure that out from the equation I got ?

Comment: Let $y = t/2$ and $f(0)=a$, and solve your equation $f(0) = f(2y) + 2 y^2$ for $f(t)$.  That tells you what function $f$ is, up to a constant.  Then plug that in to the original equation and see what you get.

Comment: The conclusion will be that there is no such function $f$.

Comment: Why did you put $y$ as $\frac{t}{2}$ ? And what should I do with this  $a=f(t) + \frac{t^2}{2}$

Comment: $a = f(t) + t^2/2$ says $f(t) = a - t^2/2$.  As I said, that tells you what function $f$ is, up to the constant $a$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael What exactly does that statement of yours mean ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70241/discussion-between-tanuj-and-robert-israel).

Comment: It means that either you or the teacher made a mistake in writing down the question.

Comment: It should have been $f(x)+f(x+2y)+6xy = 2f(2y-x)+2y^2$.

Comment: How would $6xy$ affect the question ?